# getting only values from json data

Tags: angularjs, json

i am making a http request to /result to get json data . The data is in the format

```
[{"Name":"First","Total":830,"Passed":678,"Failed":152}]}
```

Here's the angularjs script-

```
analyzer.controller('checkvalue',function($scope,$http)
        {       

            $scope.cases = [];
            $http.get('/result').success(
                            function(data) {
                                $scope.cases = data.responseData;
                                });

                });
```

It doesn't work as it has the key and value in the data.How can i get only the values from it ?

Comment: What the output you want?

Comment: cases=First,830,678,152.   Right now cases is assigned the keys also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$scope.cases = Object.keys(data.responseData).map(function (key) {
    return data.responseData[key];
});
```

Comment: @Rahul updated. there was a typo. can you check again.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
for(var key1 in data.responseData){
  values = [];
  for(var key2 in data.responseData[key1]){
    values.push(data.responseData[key1][key2]);
  }
  $scope.cases.push(values);
}
```

or you can use the way of @Arun like this:

```
$scope.cases = Object.keys(data.responseData).map(function (key) {
    return Object.keys(data.responseData[key]).map(function (key2) {
        return data.responseData[key][key2];
    });
});
```